# Trouble using Epplus and Service.svc

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wsdl, epplus

I have a Web Site with an Service.svc file, i created this using the Add New Item -> AJAX-enabled WCF Service, for weeks, everything works fine.
Today, i imported the EPplus.dll to generate some excel files. When i try to compile i get this error

```
Error   1   Reference.svcmap: 
Failed to generate code for the service reference 'QUAY.Tractebel.COP.Servicos'.
Cannot import wsdl:portType  Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension:
System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Type 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase' is a recursive collection data contract which is not supported. 
Consider modifying the definition of collection 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase' to remove references to itself.  
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='']/wsdl:portType[@name='Servicos']  App_WebReferences/QUAY/Tractebel/COP/Servicos/
```

I have no idea how to solve it, someone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had the same problem while referencing a custom wcf class i use.
The strange problem is that on my old development pc (windows vista 32bit, visual studio 2010) i haven't got this problem, it only pops up in my new system (windows 8 64bit).
Bah.

However, i bypassed the problem opening App_WebReferences --> "your service name" --> Right click on depending Refrence icon --> "Configure service reference"

In this screen move the option button from "Reuse types in all referenced assembiles" to "Reuse types in specified assemblies" and check all the depending libraries EXCEPT EPPlus

Compile and ... voila

If someon has also a logic explanation, i'll gladly listen